# Add ImageView to RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-relativelayout

So I have created an `ImageView` programmatically in my `Activity`.
I want to add this `ImageView` at the bottom of one of my `RelativeLayout`.

This is what I tried:

```
// creating new ImageView
ImageView shadowView = new ImageView (contextPara);
shadowView.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.bottomBar_Shadow);
shadowView.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FitXy);

// creating ImageView LayoutParams
WindowManagerLayoutParams imgViewLayoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams ();
imgViewLayoutParams.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
imgViewLayoutParams.Height = (int)imgViewHeight;
imgViewLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;

// Adding ImageView to RelativeLayout
listViewRelativeLayout.AddView (shadowView, imgViewLayoutParams);
```

My problem is this adds the `ImageView` to the TOP of the `RelativeLayout`, NOT the bottom.

I also tried the following:
After I call the `AddView` and add the `ImageView`, I set the `Y` position of the `ImageView`.
This actually works.  It moves the `ImageView` down but I'm not sure how much to move down.  `RelativeLayout` size is not absolute.

```
// this moves the ImageView down 100px.
shadowView.SetY (100f);
```

How can I put it to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout`?

Please note: I CAN'T just do the math (`RelativeLayout` height - `ImageView` Height) because `RelativeLayout` height is always `0` until `OnCreate` finishes.

What are my other choices?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you going to be adding more than one ImageView? You could potentially add the ImageView via XML, and just imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE), and imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) when you need it to be shown.

Comment: There are already 4 views inside the `RelativeLayout`.  I would like to do this programmatically because I will be doing this in many different places throughout my app. So my plan was to create a common function where I pass the `RelativeLayout` and it does it.  If it's via XML, I have to do it one at a time for each `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!

Instead of using `WindowManagerLayoutParams` to set LayoutParameters, using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` does the job.

Here's how:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, (int)imgViewHeight);
layoutParams.AddRule (LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
```

`AlignParentBottom` does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions:

1.

Consider placing a single ImageView within the RelativeLayout XML.

You can access this ImageView inside the Activity/Fragment using

`ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);`

You can set the starting visibility as gone `mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, and show the ImageView at a later time `mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`;

2.

You can add a sub-layout (LinearLayout) to the existing RelativeLayout, this sub-layout can be placed at the bottom of the RelativeLayout via XML.

Inside the Activity/Fragment, you can target that sub-layout (linearLayout) by its ID, and than add the ImageView programmatically to that layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.modup.fragment.FeedFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
       <LinearLayout>
              android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: XML solution isn't what I am looking for.  Please see my comment that I just added above.  Thanks.

Comment: second solution would work but I would have to add the `LinearLayout` to all `RelativeLayout`s manually.  That is basically the same idea as adding `ImageView` to `RelativeLayout`.  I wanted to add something to `RelativeLayout` directly without making any changed to XML.